# Finding total session time of a user in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to create a query that will give me a column of total time logged in for each month for each user.

```
username | auth_event_type |         time        | credential_id 

Joe      |       1         | 2021-11-01 09:00:00 | 44
Joe      |       2         | 2021-11-01 10:00:00 | 44
Jeff     |       1         | 2021-11-01 11:00:00 | 45
Jeff     |       2         | 2021-11-01 12:00:00 | 45
Joe      |       1         | 2021-11-01 12:00:00 | 46    
Joe      |       2         | 2021-11-01 12:30:00 | 46
Joe      |       1         | 2021-12-06 14:30:00 | 47
Joe      |       2         | 2021-12-06 15:30:00 | 47
```

The auth_event_type column specifies whether the event was a login (1) or logout (2) and the credential_id indicates the session.

I'm trying to create a query that would have an output like this:

```
username | year_month | total_time
Joe      | 2021-11    | 1:30
Jeff     | 2021-11    | 1:00
Joe      | 2021-12    | 1:00
```

How would I go about doing this in postgres? I am thinking it would involve a window function? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: wow. lucky you have explicit logouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 partially working**

Not sure that window functions will help you in your case, but aggregate functions will :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT username
     , date_trunc('month', time) AS year_month
     , max(time ORDER BY time) - min(time ORDER BY time) AS session_duration
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY username, date_trunc('month', time), credential_id
 )
SELECT username
     , to_char (year_month, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_month
     , sum(session_duration) AS total_time
  FROM list
 GROUP BY username, year_month
```

The first part of the query aggregates the login/logout times for the same username, credential_id, the second part makes the sum per year_month of the difference between the login/logout times. This query works well until the login time and logout time are in the same month, but it fails when they aren't.

**Solution 2 fully working**

In order to calculate the `total_time` per username and per month whatever the login time and logout time are, we can use a time range approach which intersects the session ranges `[login_time, logout_time)` with the monthly ranges `[monthly_start_time, monthly_end_time)` :

```
WITH monthly_range AS
(
SELECT to_char(m.month_start_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
     , tsrange(m.month_start_date, m.month_start_date+ interval '1 month' ) AS monthly_range
  FROM
     ( SELECT generate_series(min(date_trunc('month', time)), max(date_trunc('month', time)), '1 month') AS month_start_date
         FROM your_table
     ) AS m
), session_range AS
(
SELECT username
     , tsrange(min(time ORDER BY auth_event_type), max(time ORDER BY auth_event_type)) AS session_range
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY username, credential_id
)
SELECT s.username
     , m.month
     , sum(upper(p.period) - lower(p.period)) AS total_time
  FROM monthly_range AS m
 INNER JOIN session_range AS s
    ON s.session_range && m.monthly_range
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT s.session_range * m.monthly_range AS period) AS p
 GROUP BY s.username, m.month
```

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=88e75e6a5584306b4d76deb2e3ff7e0e)

Answer (score 2):

Use the window function `lag()` with a partition it by `credential_id` ordered by `time`, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT username, time, age(time, LAG(time) OVER w)
  FROM t
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY credential_id ORDER BY time
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
) 
SELECT username, to_char(time,'yyyy-mm'),sum(age) FROM j
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

**Note**: the frame `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is pretty much optional in this case, but it is considered a good practice to keep window functions as explicit as possible, so that in the future you don't have to read the docs to figure out what your query is doing.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ad64d116afb3377bb3a487f1ee1aa98c)

Comment: `username` should br added to the PARTITION BY clause of the first window. This solution is fine until the login time and the logout time of the same `credential_id` don't share the same month.

Comment: @Edouard Although the OP didn't mention this behavior, you're totally right. I just took into account the data provided. Thanks for the observation +1